# hardinfo network interface bit rate vs speedtest-cli : how calculated, why the difference

Tags: networking, wireless

Hardinfo gives a bitrate for my wifi device between 500 and 800 Mbs. But when I run an internet speedtest using speedtest-cli the bitrate is between 2 and 400.

Since the hardinfo rate fluctuates I assume it is based not on some feature of the device but on some communication.

1. How does hardinfo get its speed rating?

This doesn't seem to be a traffic issue because on my wired machine, connected to the same network, the speedtest-cli reports between 2 and 625 for the same time periods.

Since hardinfo reports the wifi device at 800, my limited understanding suggests that the speedtest-cli should be reporting closer to the speeds on the wired machine.

2. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, *hardinfo* reports the speed at 866.7 Mb/s. This is the same as reported in the terminal command iwconfig:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"GBR5"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: xx:2B:B0:DC:45:xx  
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          <snip>
```

This tells me that I am connected to my wireless router that supports 802.11ac speeds. That means that, in a laboratory setting with no radio frequency interference, no bluetooth, no lighting dimmers, no microwaves and, probably a mu-metal shield over the room, with my computer sitting right next to the router, it is theoretically possible to achieve 866.7 Mb/s speeds.

However, we all live in the real world. There is a lot of radio frequency interference in the real world, including other wireless access points, some of which are on the same frequency as ours. Here is what my wireless card sees right now:

```
IN-USE  SSID   MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        GBR1   Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
*       GBR5   Infra  149   405 Mbit/s  69      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        MC1    Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        nx2.4  Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        MC5    Infra  153   195 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA2
```

Because we don't sit right next to the router, speeds go down as we get farther from the router. As you see above, I am actually sending and receiving to GBR5 at a maximum of 405 Mb/s.

So far, we have only learned about the connection from the computer to the router. We are also interested in the connection from the router to the internet service provider (ISP), to the internet and return. The command-line tool speedtest-cli is one of many ways to test this. It selects a nearby server, typically provided by your ISP, downloads a package and uploads a package and measures the time elapsed and reports it.

This will be influenced by the TCP/IP overhead, typically 4-5%, whether the internet connection is shared or dedicated (https://www.telappliant.com/blog/difference-shared-and-dedicated-internet/) and, if shared, how many of your neighbors are on line at the time.

In short, hardinfo tells us what is theoretically possible and speedtest-cli tell us what has actually been achieved in the real world.